# Firma de una función que puede devuelve un template

Tags: c++11, clase-abstracta

Bueno tengo la siguiente duda.

Tengo el siguiente template.

```
#ifndef ATOM_H_
#define ATOM_H_


#include "Print.h"
//#include "Elemento.h"
template <typename T>

class Atom{
    T atomo;
public:
    Atom(T elemento_aux);
    ~Atom();
    T evaluar();
    void print(Print& print);
};

#endif /*ATOM_H_*/
```

Y tengo una función que puede devolver un `Atom<int>` o `Atom<string>`
mi duda es como debería ser la firma de la función?

Probé con

```
Atom<> funcion();

Atom funcion();

Atom* funcion();
```

Cómo sería?

La idea sería algo de estilo

```
funcion("1"):Atom<int>

funcion("a"):Atom<string>
```

Suponiendo que existe una forma genérica de decir que una función devuelve un Atom de cualquier tipo, existe una forma de castear?

Osea hacer algo de este estilo?

```
Atom<int> atomo = funcion("1").
```

Muchas gracias por tiempo.
Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ no permite, de base, implementar funciones variando únicamente el valor de retorno. Esto afecta también a los templates de funciones.

Un truco que se puede hacer para salvar éste obstáculo es haciendo que el valor de retorno de la función venga proporcionado "desde fuera" por un template auxiliar:

```
template<class T>
struct ReturnHelper
{
  typedef T ReturnType;
};

template<class T>
ReturnHelper<T>::ReturnType funcion(/* ... */ )
{ /* ... */ }
```

Este mecanismo se puede complementar facilmente. Si, por ejemplo, para la especialización `float` se desea que se retorne un `double` se puede implementar una especialización del helper:

```
template<>
struct ReturnHelper<float>
{
  typedef double ReturnType;
};
```

Sobre este tema hay diferentes versiones pero la base sobre la que se sustentan es la misma siempre.

Un saludo.